# How and why [1,2,3] == "1,2,3" returns true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know why this happens and what is the primitive value of "a"?

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = "1,2,3"
a==b //this returns true
```

As far as I know when doing this the primitive type of a is compared with b.

**EDIT:**

According to the section ["Loose equality using =="](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)
When you compare an object (a) with a string (b) the following rule is valid:

ToPrimitive(A) attempts to convert its object argument to a primitive value, **by attempting to invoke varying sequences of A.toString and A.valueOf methods on A.**

Undestanding how "ToPrimitive(A)" works was crucial.

Comment: `==` specifically ignores the type of the values it compares.

Comment: you should check this out https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat, it won't answer your question and it'll give you  a dozen more.

Comment: Ok but it fails when there is an object inside it

Comment: Generaly in js, using `===` is safer and less random than `==`. But check Miniver Cheevy's link

Comment: Use a===b. For the object, share example

Comment: If it "fails when there is an object inside it" then the string representation of the array isn't equal to the string you're comparing with.

Comment: Objects are unique. { "key" : 1 } == { "key" : 1 } is false. If you want to comapre simple objects, you can JSON.stringify() them and comapre the string. For complex objects, you need a loop.

Comment: == does type conversion so its being converted to a string, which is "1,2,3"...I think.  why the downvotes, this is a legit question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: Didn't downvote, but these are trivial js things you learn early in tutorials, so ppl downvote because it shows not enough effort.

Comment: I really checked into it, going to primitive types and all...People are kind of mad here.

Comment: Always look on MDN and such first, it's the best reference imho. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators Maybe the tutorials you use are bad if they didn't explain the diff in the first chapters. Have fun learning. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It returns `true` because you are not using the strict comparison operator `===`.

When using `==` you are actually doing `[1,2,3].toString() === '1,2,3'`

> **Equality (==)** ([*source*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_()))
>
> The equality operator converts the operands if they are not of the
>   same type, then applies strict comparison. If both operands are
>   objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal
>   when operands refer to the same object in memory.
>
> **Identity / strict equality (===)** ([*source*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_()))
>
> The identity operator returns true if the operands are strictly equal
>   (see above) with no type conversion.

```js
console.log('[1,2,3] == "1,2,3"', [1,2,3] == "1,2,3");

console.log('[1,2,3] === "1,2,3"', [1,2,3] === "1,2,3");

console.log('[1,2,3].toString() === "1,2,3"', [1,2,3].toString() === "1,2,3");
```

> **The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm** ([*source*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3))
>
> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or
>   false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> **1**.If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
>
> ____**a**. If Type(x) is **Undefined**, return **true**.
>
> ____**b**. If Type(x) is **Null**, return **true**.
>
> ____**c**. If Type(x) is **Number**, then
>
> ________**i** If x is **NaN**, return **false**.
>
> ________**ii** If y is **NaN**, return **false**.
>
> ________**iii** If x is the same Number value as y, return **true**.
>
> ________**iv** If x is +0 and y is −0, return **true**.
>
> ________**v** If x is −0 and y is +0, return **true**.
>
> ________**vi** Return **false**.
>
> ____**d**. If Type(x) is String, then return true if x and y are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in
>   corresponding positions). Otherwise, return **false**.
>
> ____**e**. If Type(x) is Boolean, return **true** if x and y are both **true** or both **false**. Otherwise, return **false**.
>
> ____**f** Return **true** if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return **false**.
>
> **2**. If x is **null** and y is **undefined**, return **true**.
>
> **3**. If x is **undefined** and y is **null**, return **true**.
>
> **4**. If Type(x) is **Number** and Type(y) is **String**,
>       return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
>
> **5**. If Type(x) is **String** and Type(y) is **Number**,
>       return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
>
> **6**. If Type(x) is **Boolean**, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
>
> **7**. If Type(y) is **Boolean**, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
>
> **8**. If Type(x) is either **String** or **Number** and Type(y) is **Object**,
>       return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).
>
> **9**. If Type(x) is **Object** and Type(y) is either **String** or **Number**,
>       return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.
>
> **10**. Return **false**.

Comment: So any type that I compare not using the strict operator is going to convert the values to string?

Comment: When using it for primitive types, generally yes :) (_The equality operator converts the operands if they are not of the same type, then applies strict comparison._)

Comment: you may add a link to the table: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: References added :). Thank you all

Comment: @NinaScholz The table in the "Loose equality using ==" is just what I was looking for

Comment: Your answer does not match the [rules here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3). I think it very misleading/wrong to be saying that different types are converted to string and then compared

Comment: @musefan this link was the origin of my question hahaha. The table that NinaScholz posted solved it